# multiple insert data in one table

Tags: html, multiple-insert

I have 120 student in 4 class A,B,C,D in student table : Id_student, Name, Class and I have a payment table: Id, Id_student, Class, Payment, Date_payment, Status How i asking how to insert All student in class A with status not_complete

Comment: is this related to html or sql?

Comment: where you want to insert?

Comment: related in sql, in payment table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO payment (Id_student, Class, Status)
SELECT Id_student, Class, "not_complete" AS Status
FROM student
WHERE Class = "A";
```

Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

insert all
into payment values(R1001,'A',"not complete")
into payment values(S1002,'B',"not complete")
into payment values(T1003,'C',"not complete")
into payment values(T1003,'C',"not complete")
into payment values(Z1003,'D',"not complete")
............
Update payment set class='A' where class in('B','C','D');
SELECT Id_student, Class, Status
FROM payment
WHERE Class = "A";